# Multiple plot function R

Tags: r, function, plot

I am new to R and have been trying to find a solution to this for the past week via google and forums. 
My problem: I have a data set which I need to plot against age. There are over a 1000 variables with different measurement during in 40 different conditions. 
Looks like this:

```
Age   Variables1  Variable2 (....) Variable1000 > 
 |        |
 |        |
 v        v
```

What I need to do is plot the condition(age) against each of the columns of variables and output as different plots (all of this is just scatterplots). What is more, I want the output to be limited to only those variables that have a positive trend line coefficient.

So currently I have this very ugly code that is essentially a rough draft of what I really need.

```
plotest <- function(lung){
  # need to add the condition of abline function coefficient > 0 before plotting    
  plot(lung$Age, lung$hsa.let.7a.1, xlab = "Age", ylab = "miRNA")
  abline(lm(lung$hsa.let.7a.1 ~ lung$Age), col= "red")
  return(plot)
}
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for (i in lung{plotest(i)})
```

I know this is mostly wrong. So sorry for the horrendous everything about it.

Could anyone direct me to any sources, which I might have overlooked in how to specify ranges in such large datasets? And function grammar? I have done some Python but found R to be much more confusing in this regard...

Thanks all,
Paul

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what you're asking. It sounds like you still just don't understand how R works. I would recommend reviewing the [introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html) an R book you can get from the library. Otherwise, edit your post to make it very clear what your specific programming challenge is. Do you not know how to plot? Test for trend? Iterate over columns? Subset ranges? Define a function? That's an awful lot of things to try to cover in one question.

Comment: Make a concrete example with say, 10 columns and then we can all play with the same data and maybe get to the point.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick responses, I'll look through R instruction again today (I have done a few tutorials they just didn't seem to cover the question i need...).  

I think my main problem is how to make it cycle through the dataset (say in Python you have "for i in bla") while a certain condition is present.

Again, apologies for ignorance.

Spacedman - I'll see to it, will probably attach it tomorrow morning.

Comment: R has `for(){}`- loops (and do pay attention to the closing paren before the loop {}-body) and it also has also `if(){}else{}` so it's not clear what is missing.

Comment: I guess I just approached all of this in a wrong way. Sorry for wasting everyones time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should come pretty close to what you're asking for, although what you're going to do with 1000 graphs is beyond me.

```
# make up some data
x <- seq(1,10,len=100)
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
df <- data.frame(x,y1=1+2*x+rnorm(100), 
                   y2=3-4*x+rnorm(100),
                   y3=2+0.001*x+rnorm(100))

# this does the work...
lapply(colnames(df)[-1],function(col){
  form <- formula(paste(col,"x",sep="~"))
  fit  <- lm(form,df)
  if (coef(fit)[2] >0) {
    plot(form,df)
    abline(fit)
  }
})
```

[image]

Your code was not that far off. This example takes all the column names except the first one (`colnames(df)[1]`) and passes them one at a time to the function. The function creates a formula variable using the column name and the name of the first column, calls `lm(...)`, checks that the coefficient of `x` is > 0, and if so plots the data and the best fit line.

Look up the documentation on `formula(...)`, `lm(...)`, and `coef(...)`. Note that this example has a variable, `y3` with a slope that is positive, but not significantly different from 0. You should think about how you want to deal with that situation.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but might I ask on how to add a write.csv(stuff_want, file = "cow.csv") function under the if statement in this case. currently I've tried establishing a data frame outside and inside the lapply(). 

I've tried this mostly, but the csv file only has NA values. 
" lapply(.... {  
stuff_want <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 500, nrow = 40))
  if (coef(fit)[2] >0) { #plotting with condition
    stuff_want <- stuff_want$df # problem lies here
    write.csv(stuff_want, file = "cow.csv")
  } "

Comment: This would be better as a new question. Your code `stuff_want <- data.frame(matrix(nc=500,nr=40))` creates a data frame with 500 columns and 40 rows, filled with `NA`. The statement `stuff_want <- stuff_want$df` looks for a column named `df`, which as far as I can see doesn't exist. So this should set `stuff_want` to `NULL`. I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish...