# Transfer of columns from one data frame to another under conditional statement

Tags: r, csv

I have this code which was mostly written by one of the members here that exports all the graphs I need from my data set under the condition that the trendline coefficient is positive (increasing trendline).

```
lung <- read.csv("LAC.csv")
attach(lung)        #data 
age <- lung$Age
mirna <- data.frame(lung)
stuff <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 500, nrow = 40))

pdf("test.pdf") # exports to pdf all the graphs

lapply(colnames(mirna)[-1],function(col){    #function for plotting 
  form <- formula(paste(col, "age", sep = "~"))
  fit  <- lm(form, mirna)
  stuff_want <- stuff 
  if (coef(fit)[2] >0) { #plotting with condition
    plot(form, df, xlab = "Age", main= "miRNA expression with increasing age")
    abline(fit, col = 4)
  }
})  

dev.off()
```

This gives me a pdf file which I was hoping to use later to check which of the miRNA in the dataset are required and isolate the columns manually. However, I severely underestimated the number of mirRNA that meet the condition and now face a new conundrum on how to export the data from a column with and increasing trendline into a separate data frame which I would later save as a .csv file and use for further analysis.

Please keep in mind my knowledge of R is very limited although I am spending days in Rhelp and books. My idea was to create a separate data frame (stuff_want) to which the columns that satisfy the condition (coef(lm()) > 0) will be transferred. My initial thought was to use append() function and under the if condition write `append(stuff_want, mirna, after = length(mirna))` followed by `write.csv()` function. The output of this is just NA filled .csv file.

Anyone able to explain to me why this is not working?

All the best,
Paulius

Comment: Replacing the code after `if (coef(fit)[2] >0)` by `if (coef(fit)[2] >0) col` should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is one way (similar to @agstudy's comment), using the same made up data as in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979421/multiple-plot-function-r/25980755#25980755)

```
# make up some data
x <- seq(1,10,len=100)
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
df <- data.frame(x,y1=1+2*x+rnorm(100), 
                   y2=3-4*x+rnorm(100),
                   y3=2+0.001*x+rnorm(100))

# you start here... 
result <- sapply(colnames(df)[-1],function(col){
  form <- formula(paste(col,"x",sep="~"))
  fit  <- lm(form,df)
  if(coef(fit)[2] > 0) TRUE else FALSE
})
cols <- names(result)[result]
cols
# [1] "y1" "y3"
```

This creates a named vector, `result` which elements have the same names as your response variables, and values = `TRUE` if that variable has positive slope, `FALSE` otherwise. Then

```
cols <- names(result)[result]
```

is a vector of the variable names with slope > 0. Finally, to extract the actual data, you would use:

```
stuff_want <- stuff[,cols]
```